# Weak convergence, measurability, uniform integrability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

I've been facing the following problems:

a) Let $ X_n \rightarrow X $ and $f $ be a measurable, bounded function. Prove that $ \mathbb{E}f(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}f(X) $ (we also assume that the set of points of discontinuity of $ f $ is of measure 0)

b) Prove that $ X_n \xrightarrow{d}X \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}X \leq \liminf \mathbb{E}X_n $.

c) Let $ X_n \xrightarrow d X $ and $ \forall_n  X_n$ are uniformly integrable. Prove then $ X $ is uniformly integrable.

As to a) I can't seem to be able to find a proper way to use f's measurability. All I know that pre-images of measurable sets are measurable.

In b) I obviously am going to need Fatou's lemma. I have:

$ \mathbb{E}\liminf X_n \leq \liminf \mathbb{E}X_n$. Now how can I associate the limes inferior of $ X_n $ to its 'weak' limit?

Comment: In (a), what is the meaning of $X_n\to X$? Regardless of the meaning, the statement is probably false. Let $f(t)=0$ if $t\le 0$ and $f(t)=1$ when $t>0$. Also let $X_n\equiv 1/n$, so that $X_n\to 0$. Then $Ef(X_n) =  1$ for all $n$ but $E(f(X))=0$.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to be convergence in distribution, and that the condition on the function is continuous, not measurable

Comment: I'm sorry. If the function was continuous, the statement would be obvious. Actually I forgot about one assumption. It's correct now